# Retrieve Result from mongodb using $and and $in

Tags: java, mongodb

**my schema design is i want to retrieve some information from mongodb**

```
{
        "_id" : "23423q53q45345",       
        "value" : "5942178562002.65",   
        "dataset" : "GDP (current US$)",
        "data" : [
                { 
                        "data_name" : "country",
                        "value" : "india"
                },
                {
                        "data_name" : "date",
                        "value" : "2011"
                }
        ]
},  
{
        "_id" : "23423q53qdsfsd5",       
        "value" : "1234238562002.65",   
        "dataset" : "GDP (current US$)",
        "data" : [
                {
                        "data_name" : "country",
                        "value" : "india"
                },
                {
                        "data_name" : "date",
                        "value" : "2012"
                }
        ]
},
{
        "_id" : "213423q45345",       
        "value" : "6576867562002.65",   
        "dataset" : "GDP (current US$)",
        "data" : [
                { 
                        "data_name" : "country",
                        "value" : "us"
                },
                {
                        "data_name" : "date",
                        "value" : "2011"
                }
        ]
},
{
        "_id" : "4564564545dsfsd5",       
        "value" : "2354353462002.65",   
        "dataset" : "GDP (current US$)",
        "data" : [
                {
                        "data_name" : "country",
                        "value" : "us"
                },
                {
                        "data_name" : "date",
                        "value" : "2012"
                }
        ]
}
```

**i want to get data of india for 2011**

**i used this query**

```
db.collection.find({
    "data.value": {
        "$in": [
            "india","2011"
        ]
    }
});
```

**it returns two results**

```
{
        "_id" : "23423q53q45345",       
        "value" : "5942178562002.65",   
        "dataset" : "GDP (current US$)",
        "data" : [
                { 
                        "data_name" : "country",
                        "value" : "india"
                },
                {
                        "data_name" : "date",
                        "value" : "2011"
                }
        ]
},  
{
        "_id" : "23423q53qdsfsd5",       
        "value" : "1234238562002.65",   
        "dataset" : "GDP (current US$)",
        "data" : [
                {
                        "data_name" : "country",
                        "value" : "india"
                },
                {
                        "data_name" : "date",
                        "value" : "2012"
                }
        ]
}
```

**it suppose to be one result**

```
{
        "_id" : "23423q53q45345",       
        "value" : "5942178562002.65",   
        "dataset" : "GDP (current US$)",
        "data" : [
                { 
                        "data_name" : "country",
                        "value" : "india"
                },
                {
                        "data_name" : "date",
                        "value" : "2011"
                }
        ]
}
```

**i know that query is wrong but how to achieve that please help me out**

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.find({
    $and: [
        {"data.value": "india"},
        {"data.value": "2011"}
    ]
});
```